# Mutliple views for detail in a master-detail interface

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, master-detail

I am building a preferences pane for an app where the user can add a Web Service to a list (in a tableview on the left) and a form should appear on the right where the user can edit configuration options for the web service (like username or password or API key or tumblr blog name, etc.) I think I'll need different views for different types of service (possibly with different logic for validation and so on).

My question is what is the best way to implement this?

*What I've done:* I have a `NSSplitView` with a `NSTableView`. I have an `NSArrayController` with it's `content` bound to the appropriate key in `NSUserDefaultsController` and the `NSTableView` bound to it's `arrangedObjects` and `selectionIndexes`. Next I've added a `NSTabView` in the right with it's `selectedIndex` bound to the `NSArrayController`'s selectedIndex and I'm trying to programatically insert the appropriate views (which I've created as separate custom views in IB) as tabs.

This seems to me to be a not the best approach. I also don't know what to bind the fields in the detail views - is it even possible to use bindings here? How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `NSTabView`, create a blank `NSView` for the inspector (`inspectorView`). Same idea, but a little simpler.

In `tableViewSelectionDidChange`, write something like:

```
newView = ...;

if (inspectorView != [customInspectorView superview]) {
    NSView *oldView = [[inspectorView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
    [inspectorView replaceSubview:oldView with:newView];
}
```

You can bind your fields to `servicesArrayController.selection.username` and so on.